Subconvexity bounds for Dedekind zeta functions of cyclotomic fields
I am looking for hybrid subconvexity bounds on $|\zeta_K(1/2+it)|$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_n)$ is the cyclotomic field with $n$th roots of unity. Basically, I am looking for
$$|\zeta_K(1/2+it)| \ll |\Delta_K|^{1/4 - \eta_1} |t|^{\deg K \cdot \eta_2}, \text{ for }t\geq t_0$$
where the implied constant does not depend on $n$ and $t_0$ is independent of $n$. I want $\eta_2$ as small as possible as long as $\eta_1 > 0$.
The cheapest way I could get something like this seems to be using the following formula.
$$\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\chi:\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathbb{C} } L(s,\chi)$$
where $L(s,\chi)$ is a Dirichlet $L$-function. These subconvexity bounds are known due to Burgess and completely explicit versions seem to be available but I could not find something where $\eta_2 < 1$.
However, there seems to be a second way to attack this, by writing $\zeta_K(s)$ as the Hecke $L$-functions of the trivial character. This is where my newly built knowledge of subconvexity reaches it's limits and it would be nice to know if this can give anything better.
So what are the currently best known explicit versions of subconvexity bounds for Dedekind zeta functions of cyclotomic fields?

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

For Dirichlet $L$-functions, the best known hybrid subconvexity bound is due to Petrow and Young (see the published version or the arXiv preprint). From this result, the first displayed bound follows for any $\eta_1<1/12$ and any $\eta_2>1/6$.

That's awesome! Thanks.
